# Pinnacle Studio - png transparency - exported wtih Gimp

Tags: png, gimp, video-editing, paint.net

I am trying to import the png image with transparent background to Pinnacle Studio, but unfortunatelly the alpha channel is ignored as background has black color.

Comment: The best place to ask for why this happen would be a Pinnacle Studio forum. And it's off topic here, as a tech support question it should be moved to SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Gimp, use Paint.net to export the image with transparent background. Althought the Gimp exported files are interpreted as transparent in all other software (IrfanView, Internet Browsers, etc.), the Pinnacle Studio accepts only those from Paint.net. I can not explain this, but may be I save you 4 hours of investigating :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats works on me: Image → Mode → RGB